# Problem with UI interaction with XR interaction Toolkit in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, virtual-reality

I'm working on a VR project for HTC Vive Cosmos headset and have a huge problem with UI interactions.

- I was able to configute XR Rig with both controllers (left and right) which have an XR ray interactor.
- Canvas has Tracked Device Graphic Raycaster script and Graphic Raycaster
- EventSystem has XR UI Input Module
- There is an XR interaction Manager object in the scene with XR interaction manager script on it.

The project loads and I can see the rays representing both controllers, but when I try to interact with the UI button nothing happens.

What I tried:

- I of course read a documentation from Unity to XR Interaction Toolkit, especially UI setup section.
- I set raycast target off for all other UI elements that do not require interaction.
- I checked if the buttons have "interactable" on.
- I checked if there were some transparent UI elements that could be overlapping my buttons.

Nothing seems to be working and I got a feeling, the problem is not in UI elements, but in configuring the toolkit itself. Have you any ideas what can I check/change to make UI interactions work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved and it was more an attention error.
My controllers have an XR Ray Interactor and it has a property Max Raycast Distance (in Inspector -> XR Ray Interactor -> Raycast Configuration -> Max Raycast Distance).
So basically my UI Elements were too far for interactor to detect them. I altered the Max Raycast Distance value and everything now works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem in one of my scenes.

It seems that I used a normal Canvas, instead of using the XR UI Canvas, which integrated an "InputSystemUIInputModule" component to the EventSystem, instead of the "XR UI Input Module" component.

I hope this will help you.

[The "normal" canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoBpi.png)

[The XR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H83cq.png)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! In my case it was a little different problem. I'll post it as an answer